# how to double click on a list of webElements in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

From a list of similar elements I was able to get the element I wanted.

```
List<WebElement> expandQA = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains(@class, 'x-tree-expander')]/following-sibling::span[text()='QA']"))
expandQA.get(2);
```

Now I want to double click on that element. How could I do that?

Tried using the below code but I'm getting a error.

```
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        List<WebElement> expandQA = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains(@class, 'x-tree-expander')]/following-sibling::span[text()='QA']"));
        e = expandQA.get(2);
        actions.doubleClick(e);
```

Comment: What error?  It matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

java code...

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.doubleClick(myElemment);
action.perform();`

Answer (score 0):

This should double-click on the element.
import the following statements

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

create an object from Actions class(where the driver is your Webdriver object)

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
```

Write the code like below.

```
action.moveToElement(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your xpath here")))).doubleClick().perform();
```

This should perform the double-click.