# How to Simulate double mouse click in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I want to be able to click a logout button twice very rapidly like a user would?

```
WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label"));{

  if(logout.isDisplayed()){
    logout.click();
```

I want to be able to click on the logout button twice at less than a second like a user would? Is this possible in selenium webdriver?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to double click on a list of webElements in Selenium webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908556/how-to-double-click-on-a-list-of-webelements-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);{
      if(logout.isDisplayed()){
    action.doubleClick(logout); 
    action.perform();
    Reporter.log("Logout Successful  | "); }

This doesn't work do I need to use a try/catch block? @Atri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

### Make sure the dom is loaded

Like [atri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043569/atri) said, you could use the double click function according to [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908556/how-to-double-click-on-a-list-of-webelements-in-selenium-webdriver).

```
WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label"));{

  if(logout.isDisplayed()){
    logout.doubleClick();
```

if you don't want to use the doubleClick function, I would recommend the ExplicitWait from Selemium 
[Selenium: Implicit and explicit Wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

If you want to do this manually, could add a delay between your click using javascript Thread and selenium wait.
Based on [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009211/getting-selenium-to-pause-for-x-seconds)

```
WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label"));{

  if(logout.isDisplayed()){
    logout.click();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    logout.click();
}
```

> Better way is to use ExplicitWaits which you means you will wait
>   exactly as long as some action happens or some element gets rendered
>   on the page.
>   [- petr-mensik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039952/petr-mensik)
>
> An explicit waits is code you define to wait for a certain condition
>   to occur before proceeding further in the code. The worst case of this
>   is Thread.sleep(), which sets the condition to an exact time period to
>   wait. [- Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)